# Админ панель для телеграм бота

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Всем добрый день. Захотелось сделать телеграм бота на Python. Если пользователь нажимает на кнопку (бот присылает сообщение и кнопку), то он переходит на оплату товара ,т.е. на free-kassa переходит и оплачивает (в моем случаи товар - это подписка, причем подписка имеет определённый срок действия для разных кнопок). оплату хочу реализовать с помощью Free-kassa. Нужна админ панель, где будет показан id покупателя (в телеграм), время покупки и название продукта. Как сделать админ панель? Любой способ, главное чтобы она была. Бд в этом случае вообще нужна? Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

users = [123, 456]

```
if message.chat.id not in users:
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'не админ')
```

Answer (score 2):

Тебе нужна админ панель в телеграмме или на сайте?
Если телеграмм, есть несколько способов проверки:

1. Самая простая:
   Ты узнаешь id своего телеграмма.

```
user = message.from_user.id
print(user)
if (user == Твой ID В цифрах):
# Выводишь дополнительную кнопку в инлайте
elif (user != Твой ID):
# простой вывод меню
```

2. Ты делаешь в таблице дополнительный столбец с дефолтным значением 0.
   Опять же узнаешь ID
   После своему ID в дополнительном столбце ставишь 1.
   После делаешь запрос в базу данных с проверкой
   После ищешь совпадения

```
import re
if re.search(str(1), str(#Выводишь весь столбец из Базы данных)):
    print('админ')
else:
    print('не админ')
```

P.S. Функционал админ панели это совершенно другой вопрос

Answer (score 0):

```
admins_id = [321312, 412412]
for admin in admins_id:
    if message.from_user.id == admin:
        return True
    else:
        pass
return False
```

в админ айди вносите айди админов, этот код вносите в функцию и вызываете эту функцию при проверке, если функция возвратила False, то человек не является админом, а если True, то является

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: готово, теперь более подробное описание